# Javascript Tooltip hover and click

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I need some help with a tooltip in javascript. The code I have below works well on the hover, but I can't put the function outside so it can be called with the click. In the function there is just stuff for calculating the tooltip position and the way that it appears, and that works.

Thank you very much for your help.

```
var targets = $( '[rel~=tooltip]' ),
    target  = false,
    tooltip = false,
    title   = false;

targets.on( 'mouseenter', function()
{
    target  = $( this );
    tip     = target.attr( 'title' );
    tooltip = $( '<div id="tooltip"></div>' );



    if( !tip ) {
        return false;
    }

    target.removeAttr( 'title' );
    tooltip.css( 'opacity', 0 )
           .html( tip )
           .appendTo( 'body' );

    var init_tooltip = function()
    {
        containerList = $('.container').find('.listImages');

        if( containerList.width() < tooltip.outerWidth() * 1.5 )
            tooltip.css( 'max-width', containerList.width() / 2);
        else
            tooltip.css( 'max-width', 340 );

        var pos_left = target.offset().left + ( target.outerWidth() / 2 ) - ( tooltip.outerWidth() / 2 ),
            pos_top  = target.offset().top + target.outerHeight(),
            pos_right = target.offset().right + ( target.outerWidth() / 2 ) - ( tooltip.outerWidth() / 2 );

            console.log(pos_right)

        if( pos_left < containerList.offset().left )
        {
            pos_left = target.offset().left;
            tooltip.addClass( 'left' );
        }
        else {
            tooltip.removeClass( 'left' );
        }

        if( pos_left + tooltip.outerWidth() > containerList.offset().left + containerList.width() )
        {
            pos_left = target.offset().left - tooltip.outerWidth() + target.outerWidth();
            tooltip.addClass( 'right' );
        }
        else {
            tooltip.removeClass( 'right' );
        }


        if( pos_top < 0 )
        {
            var pos_top  = target.offset().top + target.outerHeight();
            tooltip.addClass( 'top' );
        }
        else {
            tooltip.removeClass( 'top' );
        }

        tooltip.css( { left: pos_left, top: pos_top } )
               .animate( { top: '+=10', opacity: 1 }, 50 );
    };

    init_tooltip();
    $( window ).resize( init_tooltip );

    var remove_tooltip = function()
    {
        tooltip.animate( { top: '-=10', opacity: 0 }, 50, function()
        {
            $( this ).remove();
        });

        target.attr( 'title', tip );
    };



    target.bind( 'mouseleave', remove_tooltip );

});
```

Comment: jsfiddle will be better or atleast you can tell whats happening now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a fiddle based off of what you provided in your question: http://jsfiddle.net/R26Ba/1/

However, because I don't have a full implementation of your page it's more theory based than actually being usable within the Fiddle.

Essentially what I have done is created a Tooltip object:

```
function Tooltip(el) {
    //...
}
```

Which has prototype methods `create`, `position`, and `destroy`. Then created custom binding that created and destroyed Tooltips based on mouseevents:

```
$('[rel~=tooltip][title]').on({
    'tooltip.create': function() {
        $(this).trigger('tooltip.destroy');

        activeTooltip = new Tooltip(this);
    },
    'tooltip.destroy': function() {
        if(activeTooltip) {
            activeTooltip.destroy();
        }
    },
    'mouseenter': function() {
        $(this).trigger('tooltip.create');
    },
    'mouseleave': function() {
        $(this).trigger('tooltip.destroy');
    },
    'click': function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();

        if(activeTooltip && activeTooltip.el == this) {
            $(this).trigger('tooltip.destroy');
        } else {
            $(this).trigger('tooltip.create');
        }
    }
});

$(document.body).on('click', function() {
    if(activeToolTip) {
        activeTooltip.destroy();
    }
});

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if(activeTooltip) {
        activeTooltip.position();
    }
});
```

Also, a side note: You may notice that I cleaned up a lot of the `outerWidth/Height` and `offset` calls. These functions can be very expensive (performance wise) to call, so you really want to keep an eye out for the number of times you have to use them.

Side note 2: You may also want to use a [`resizeEnd`](https://github.com/giuseppeg/jQuery-resizeEnd) event plugin for jQuery. This will throttle the amount of calls to the `position` method and will boost the overall performance.

Side note 3: I am now laughing at myself because I went to this effort and then just realized...How are you going to click on an element *without* causing a `mouseenter` event to fire?

Comment: I have updated your fiddle based on your feedback: http://jsfiddle.net/dSxdD/3/ It would have helped if you had described the desire for this functionality in your original question.

You really shouldn't be using the solutions as a commenting thread.

Comment: I made it so the tooltip can be shown without having to redo positioning. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dSxdD/6/

Comment: ArrayKnight, I just saw the fiddle ... You make my day. Thank you very much, that's awesome.I'm watching that. I need to learn of what you did with this code

Comment: What do you think about a:

Comment: What do you think about destroy and init the tooltip from media queries, for example 768px. I tried this thing:

enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 768px)", {
    match : function() {
        $targets.off();
    },  
    unmatch : function() {
       $targets.on();
    }
});

Comment: There's no real point. That's more complicated than it needs to be. Just use a standard css media query to target the tooltip class and use display: none.

Comment: Thanks, i don't know why I have not thought before

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse your init_tooltip function, you can declare it outside of the mouseenter event, passing two parameters : target and tooltip.

The init_tooltip function definition would be like this:

```
var init_tooltip = function(target, tooltip)
```

Then in your mouseenter event, you would have:

```
init_tooltip(target, tooltip);
$( window ).resize( function () { init_tooltip(target, tooltip); } );
```

That way, you could use it for the click event handler as well, like this:

```
targets.on('click', function () {
    tooltip = $( '<div id="tooltip"></div>' );
    init_tooltip($(this), tooltip);
});
```

You might need to reproduce your logic in the click event to determine if it should show or hide the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

So that is what can i do for the moment but there is again a problem with the click and the mouseleave. I improve the code but this is not perfect.

```
$( "body" ).append( '<div id="tooltip"></div>' );

var activeTooltip = null,
    $tooltip = $('#tooltip'),
    $containerList = $('#content .listImages');

function Tooltip(el) {
    this.el = el;
    this.$el = $(el);
    this.text = this.$el.attr('data-content');

    this.create();
}

$.extend(Tooltip.prototype, {
    'create': function () {
        this.$el.removeAttr('data-content');

        $tooltip.css({
            'opacity': 0
        }).text(this.text);

        this.position();
    },
        'position': function () {
        var conWidth = $containerList.width(),
            conOffset = $containerList.offset(),
            toolWidth = $tooltip.outerWidth();

        if (conWidth < $tooltip.outerWidth() * 1.5) {
            $tooltip.css('max-width', conWidth / 2);
        } else {
            $tooltip.css('max-width', 340);
        }

        var elOffset = this.$el.offset(),
            elWidth = this.$el.outerWidth(),
            elHeight = this.$el.outerHeight(),
            pos_left = elOffset.left + (elWidth / 2) - (toolWidth / 2),
            pos_top = elOffset.top + elHeight;

        if (this.$el.offset().left + (elWidth / 2) - ($tooltip.outerWidth() / 2) < conOffset.left) {
            pos_left = this.$el.offset().left;

            $tooltip.addClass('left');
        } else {
            $tooltip.removeClass('left');
        }

        if (elOffset.left + (this.$el.outerWidth() / 2) - ($tooltip.outerWidth() / 2) + $tooltip.outerWidth() > $containerList.offset().left + $containerList.width()) {
            pos_left = this.$el.offset().left - $tooltip.outerWidth() + this.$el.outerWidth();
            $tooltip.addClass('right');
        } else {
            $tooltip.removeClass('right');
        }

        if (elOffset.top + this.$el.outerHeight() < 0) {
            pos_top = elOffset.top + this.$el.outerHeight();

            $tooltip.addClass('top');
        } else {
            $tooltip.removeClass('top');
        }

        $tooltip.css({
            'left': pos_left,
            'top': pos_top
        })
            .animate({
            'top': '+=10',
            'opacity': 1
        }, 50);
    },
        'destroy': function () {
        $tooltip.animate({
            'top': '-=10',
            'opacity': 0
        }, 50);

        this.$el.attr('data-content', this.text);

        activeTooltip = null;
    }
});

var savelastTooltip, activeSaveTooltip = false;

$('[rel~=tooltip][data-content]').on({
    'tooltip.create': function () {
        $(this).trigger('tooltip.destroy');
        activeTooltip = new Tooltip(this);
    },
    'tooltip.destroy': function () {
        if (activeTooltip) {
            activeTooltip.destroy();
        }
    },
    'mouseenter': function () {
        $(this).trigger('tooltip.create');
    },
    'mouseleave': function () {
        $(this).trigger('tooltip.destroy');
        if(true === activeSaveTooltip)
        { 
            activeTooltip = new Tooltip(savelastTooltip);
        }
    },
    'click': function (e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
       activeSaveTooltip = true;
       savelastTooltip = this;

        if (activeTooltip && activeTooltip.el != this) {
            $(this).trigger('tooltip.destroy');
        } else if(activeTooltip && activeTooltip.el == this) {
            $(this).off('mouseleave');
        } else {
            $(this).trigger('tooltip.create');
        }
    }
});

$(window).on('resize', function () {
    if (activeTooltip) {
        activeTooltip.position();
    }
});
```